# Python 3: Build a dict from text file and then search the word in dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a text file that has thousand words listed from a to z. It looks for example something like this:

```
a
aaoo
aloor
azur
black
blue
church
croccoli
dark
den
...
zic
zip
```

I need to build my dictionary whose keys are the lowercase letters, and whose values are sets of words containing
the given letter. For example:

```
myDict={'a':['aaoo','aloor','azur'], 'b':['black','blue'], 'c': ['church', 'croccoli'],'d':['dark','den'], and so on}
```

Then I need to prompt the user for a word and prints all words in the file containing all characters of the word.

```
wordFind=("Enter word: ")
wordFind=wordFind.lower()
wordFind=set(wordFind) #I convert to set to use intersection
```

For example, I type a word "abc", then 'a','b','c' in wordFind will intersect with the 'key' in myDict, the result prints out will include all the values in the key 'a','b','c' of myDict.

Edit: By "intersection" here I mean the intersection between 2 sets (wordFind and myDict) - hope this clear enough..

my code so far is:

```
n=open("a7.txt","r")

line=n.readlines()

myDict={}
def myDict():
    for word in line:
        word=word.strip().lower()
        if word in myDict:
            myDict[word[0]].append(word)
        else:
            myDict[word[0]]=word


wordFind=("Enter word: ")
wordFind=wordFind.lower()
wordFind=set(wordFind)

# I get stuck at this second part, which requires me to use intersection
temp={}
for word in wordFind:
    temp= word.intersection(myDict)
    print(temp)

    n.close()
```

But I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/annie_mabu/Documents/CS/bt2.py", line 21, in <module>
    temp= word.intersection(myDict)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'intersection'
```

Can anyone show me where did I make mistake and how to fix it?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "intersection" and don't feel like guessing. Please expand your explanation (by editing your question, not here in comments).

Comment: Neither `wordFind` or `myDict` are sets and so 'intersection' is confusing. Do you mean membership?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I need to convert that text file into dictionary like: myDict={'a':'all the word start with a', 'b': all the word start with b', and so on}*

I'd start with this function:

```
def make_dict():
    d = {}
    with open("a7.txt","r") as wordfile:
        for word in wordfile:
            word = word.strip().lower()
            first = word[0]
            if first not in d: d[first] = []
            d[first].append(word)
    return d

myDict = make_dict()
```

*then I use wordFind=("Enter word: "), when I enter a wordFind that intersect with the key value in myDict, the result will give me all the values in that intersection.*

If you just want a list of words that start with the same letter as the word you entered, then something like:

```
wordFind = raw_input("Enter word: ")   # raw_input for Python2, input for Python3
wordFind = wordFind.lower()
find_first = wordFind[0]
matches = myDict[find_first]
print(matches)
```

Should work.

If you want more extensive matching, like the words that match need to start with the same set of characters you entered, then something like:

```
wordFind = raw_input("Enter word: ")   # raw_input for Python2, input for Python3
wordFind = wordFind.lower()
find_first = wordFind[0]
matches = [w for w myDict[find_first] if w.startswith(wordFind)]  # This is different
print(matches)
```

Should work.

**Edit:** per comments:

For the input "abc", if you want a list of all the words that start with "a", "b", or "c", then something like the following should work:

```
wordFind = raw_input("Enter word: ")   # raw_input for Python2, input for Python3
wordFind = wordFind.lower()
matches = []
for c in wordFind: matches.extend(myDict[c])
print(matches)
```

If you want them separately, and not in a single list, you could do something like:

```
wordFind = raw_input("Enter word: ")   # raw_input for Python2, input for Python3
wordFind = wordFind.lower()
matches = {}
for c in wordFind: matches[c] = myDict[c]
print(matches)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The first code is exactly what I want to build myDict. But the second part is not really what Im looking for. Like I edited in my question, when I enter "abc", the result will print out all the values in 'a','b','c', instead of only 'a'...

Answer (score 1):

Just read a list with the key of each first letter:

```
with open(ur_file) as f:
    d={}
    for word in f:
        d.setdefault(word[0].lower(), []).append(word)
```

Then you have a dict like so:

```
>>> d
{'a': ['a', 'aaoo', 'aloor', 'azur'], 'c': ['church', 'croccoli'], 'b':  ['black', 'blue'], 'd': ['dark', 'den'], 'z': ['zic', 'zip']}
```

Then you can write a simple function to find your words:

```
>>> def f(s): return s in d[s[0]]
... 
>>> f('art')
False
>>> f('aaoo')
True
```

Or, if you know that you have all 26 letters in your file, you can just set all 26 to start with to empty lists:

```
d={k:list() for k in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'}
with open(ur_file) as f:
    for word in f:
        d[word[0].lower()].append(word)
```

By '.intersection' you may be thinking of [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set):

```
>>> set(['a', 'aaoo', 'aloor', 'azur']).intersection(set(['art']))
set([])
>>> set(['a', 'aaoo', 'aloor', 'azur']).intersection(set(['aaoo']))
set(['aaoo'])
```

However, whether you have a list, dict, set, string -- the `in` keyword is the best to test membership for a single element:

```
>>> 'art' in set(['a', 'aaoo', 'aloor', 'azur'])
False
>>> 'azur' in set(['a', 'aaoo', 'aloor', 'azur'])
True
```

Comment: And for the second part of your question, you'd search with `if word in d[word[0]]` instead of `if word in d`

Comment: But I's supposed to use intersection in the second part to find out which letter I find intersect with d (key), then print out the values

Answer (score 0):

You may want to expand on what you mean by "*intersection*", but try this:

```
words = [w.strip().lower() for w in open("a7.txt").read().splitlines()]

word_dict = {}
for word in words:
    if word[0] in word_dict:
        word_dict[word[0]].append(word)
    else:
        word_dict[word[0]] = [word]

wordFind = raw_input("Enter word: ").strip().lower()
print '\n'.join(word_dict[wordFind[0]])
```